# How to get data from URL after hash(#)?

Tags: php, api, url

After user log-in system i redirect it to this URL:

**sample**

```
https://www.website.com/#code=gG0YHKYU1iTRh4vVm2PWX4Bh99qWma
```

> **Question:** how i can get params after the hash (#) ?

Comment: Please add your code what you have tried. Also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you're looking to parse the text in PHP, you can use [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) but as stated in the answer, the URL `fragment` is not set in the `$_REQUEST` or `$_SERVER` global. `parse_url('https://www.website.com/#code=gG0YHKYU1iTRh4vVm2PWX4Bh99qWma', \PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);`

Answer (score 5):

Short version: It's impossible.

Slightly longer version: It's impossible through PHP. The part after the `#` isn't being sent to the server, so you can't parse it through PHP. What you want to do is use either a `$_GET` variable (read up on those [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)) or pick up the part after the hashtag through `JavaScript` by doing the following:

`var afterHashtag = window.location.hash`

Hope this helped. Cheers!

Comment: Agreed. If you want to get the URI, you'll have to replace the # with ?